# Passing data between forms c# delegate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delegates

I'm trying to pass data between forms using delegate. I'm using TrackBar and I'd like to send value from trackBar to second form. The problem is that I want to open two forms simultaneously. When I open first Form and when the slider value is change then show Form2 everything works fine. But when I open two forms simultaneosuly then nothing happen. 
I'll be grateful for any help :)

Program.cs

```
public class MultiFormContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private int openForms;
    public MultiFormContext(params Form[] forms)
    {
        openForms = forms.Length;
        foreach (var form in forms)
        {
            form.FormClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref openForms) == 0)
                    ExitThread();
            };
            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MultiFormContext(new Form2(), new Form1()));



    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public delegate void delPassData(TrackBar trackVal);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    { 
       InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         delPassData delegat = new delPassData(form2.someValFromTrackBar);

        //form2.Show();


        delegat(this.trackBar1);

    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void someValFromTrackBar(TrackBar valFromTrackBar)
    {

        label1.Text = valFromTrackBar.Value.ToString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Form1` creates an instance of `Form2`. This code creates a different instance of `Form2`:

```
Application.Run(new MultiFormContext(new Form2(), new Form1()));
```

"For some reason" (as the kids say), you didn't include the code for the version that works, but it looks very much like in the case that fails, `Form1` is subscribing to a trackbar event on the wrong instance of `Form2`.

There must be only one instance of `Form2`, and `Form1` must have a reference to it. The most straightforward way to only use the instance of `Form2` that `Form1` creates:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    public Form2 Form2 { get { return form2; } }
```

...

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var form1 = new Form1();

    Application.Run(new MultiFormContext(form1.Form2, form1));
}
```

S. Petrosov's answer will work as well, but `MultiFormContext` should not be responsible for knowing, much less implementing, the details of the relationship between those two forms. It can't do it very well, either: What if you add a second trackbar later, with some other purpose? It'll be a mess. `MultiFormContext` is a nice clean general class that does one job well. I recommend keeping it that way.

`App` shouldn't have that responsibility either, of course, but at least it's not required in my version to know anything but that there *is* a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example how you can do communication between two forms.
In this example I have two forms with `TrackBar` and `TextBox`. When `TrackBar` for one Form is scrolled the second ones `TextBox` get text "Modified from Form1" or "Modified from Form1".

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form1 = new Form1();
            var form2 = new Form2();
            Application.Run(new MultiFormContext(form1, form2));
        }
    }
    public class MultiFormContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        private int openForms;
        public MultiFormContext(Form1 form1, Form2 form2)
        {
            form1.FormClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref openForms) == 0)
                    ExitThread();
            };
            form1.Controls.OfType<TrackBar>().First().Scroll += (sender, args) =>
            {
                form2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First().Text = "Modified from Form1";
            };
            form1.Show();

            form2.FormClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref openForms) == 0)
                    ExitThread();
            };
            form2.Controls.OfType<TrackBar>().First().Scroll += (sender, args) =>
            {
                form1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First().Text = "Modified from Form2";
            };
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```